# Implementation of Blizzard's Mobile Authenticator

Tags: authentication, mobile

How is the Blizzard Mobile Authenticator implemented? Does it happen to use OATH-TOTP or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Windows client at http://code.google.com/p/winauth/ which was made by reverse-engineering the protocol. They refer to http://www.wowwiki.com/Battle.net_Mobile_Authenticator_Specification as a description of the protocol, but it's rather sketchy.

You probably have to read the source to an authenticator to get a full understanding. There's one written in python at https://github.com/Adys/python-bna that would probably be the easiest to read.

Comment: The protocol and Python implementation make it pretty straight forward. Definitely not OATH though; damn. Thanks!